# passing pointer to const int in recursive call

Tags: c++, c

How to pass a pointer to `const int` in a recursive call. I am using the following code format to calculate Fibonacci recursively, but am getting the error:

> error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand**

```
#include <iostream>

void fun(const int *n)
{    
    fun( &(*n-1) );   // it is giving error.
}
int main()
{
    const int n = 4;
    fun(&n);
}
```

Comment: Why do you pass a const, if the very purpose of this pointer is to be modified? In `fun` it is already a pointer, so you don't need to use `&`.

Comment: I don't want to modify actual(parent) value but want to pass decreased value to next recursive call.  I need to use & because (*n-1) is int type

Comment: @Nastor Thanks, it solved my problem.

Comment: Feel free to accept my official answer below then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use another variable then, to which you assign the decremented const variable: you simply can't pass a decreased value of a const variable, since by definition, it is not modifiable neither by increment or decrement.

```
#include <iostream>
void fun2 (const int *n)
{
    std::cout << *n << std::endl;
}
void fun1(const int *n)
{
    int x = *n-1;
    fun2( &x );
}
int main()
{
  const int n = 4;
  fun1(&n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as @nastor pointed out in comment using local variable problem solved.

```
#include <iostream>
void fun2 (const int *n)
{
    std::cout << *n << std::endl;
}
void fun1(const int *n)
{
    int x = *n-1;
    fun2( &x );
}
int main()
{
  const int n = 4;
  fun1(&n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void fun(const int *n)
{    
    fun( &(*n-1) );   // it is giving error.
}
```

You already passed a pointer, so you don't need to use the `&` as this would create a pointer from the pointer. Just pass the pointer. If you don't want to modifiy the parent value, then you don't need a pointer.

```
void fun(int n)
{
    if (!n)
       return;

    fun(n-1);
}

int main()
{
  const int n = 4;
  fun(n);
}
```

Comment: Well, that is valid C++, but equivalent to just write `return 0`. No Return, nothing observable .... https://godbolt.org/z/jM9xa8

Comment: You are missing one point that I am dereferencing the pointer before the use of &. So its like I am passing (&(int - 1))

Comment: If you are trying to solve another problem, you didn't say, because the example you gave, works the same as without a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

All answers are already given and correct.

Unrelated to the level of the question,  I will add the fastest possible solution for those who are interested in high speed Fibonacci number retrieval.

We simply do a **compile time** pre calculation of all Fibonacci numbers that fit into a 64 bit value. And then use a simple look up mechanism to get the value.

One important property of the Fibonacci series is that the values grow strongly exponential. So, all existing build in integer data types will overflow rather quickly.

With [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Binet%27s_formula) you can calculate that the 93rd Fibonacci number is the last that will fit in a 64bit unsigned value.

And calculating 93 values during compilation is a really simple task and does not waste that much space in the executable.

We will first define the default approach for calculation a Fibonacci number as a `constexpr` function:

```
// Constexpr function to calculate the nth Fibonacci number
constexpr unsigned long long getFibonacciNumber(size_t index) noexcept {
    unsigned long long f1{ 0ull }, f2{ 1ull }, f3{};
    while (index--) { f3 = f2 + f1; f1 = f2; f2 = f3; }
    return f2;
}
```

With that, Fibonacci numbers can easily be calculated at compile time. Then, we fill a `std::array` with all Fibonacci numbers. We use also a `constexpr` function and make it a template with a variadic parameter pack.

We use `std::index_sequence` to create a Fibonacci number for indices 0,1,2,3,4,5, ....

That is straigtforward and not complicated:

```
// Some helper to create a constexpr std::array initilized by a generator function
template <typename Generator, size_t ... Indices>
constexpr auto generateArrayHelper(Generator generator, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
    return std::array<decltype(std::declval<Generator>()(size_t{})), sizeof...(Indices) > { generator(Indices)... };
}
```

This function will be fed with an index sequence 0,1,2,3,4,... and a generator function and return a `std::array<return type of generator function, ...>` with the corresponding numbers, calculated by the generator.

We know that we can store maximum 93 values. And therefore we make a next function, that will call the above with the index sequence 1,2,3,4,...,92,93, like so:

```
template <size_t Size, typename Generator>
constexpr auto generateArray(Generator generator) {
    return  generateArrayHelper(generator, std::make_index_sequence<Size>());
}
```

And now, finally,

```
constexpr auto FibonacciNumber = generateArray<MaxArraySize64BitFibonacci>(getFibonacciNumber);
```

will give us a compile-time `std::array<unsigned long long, 93>` with the name FibonacciNumber containing all Fibonacci numbers. And if we need the i'th Fibonacci number, then we can simply write `FibonacciNumber [i]`. There will be no calculation at runtime.

I do not think that there is a faster way to calculate the n'th Fibonacci number.

Please see the complete program below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <array>

// All done during compile time -------------------------------------------------------------------
constexpr unsigned long long getFibonacciNumber(size_t index) noexcept {
    unsigned long long f1{ 0ull }, f2{ 1ull }, f3{};
    while (index--) { f3 = f2 + f1; f1 = f2; f2 = f3; }
    return f2;
}
// Some helper to create a constexpr std::array initilized by a generator function
template <typename Generator, size_t ... Indices>
constexpr auto generateArrayHelper(Generator generator, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
    return std::array<decltype(std::declval<Generator>()(size_t{})), sizeof...(Indices) > { generator(Indices)... };
}
template <size_t Size, typename Generator>
constexpr auto generateArray(Generator generator) {
    return  generateArrayHelper(generator, std::make_index_sequence<Size>());
}
constexpr size_t MaxArraySize64BitFibonacci = 93;

// This is the definition of a std::array<unsigned long long, 93> with all Fibonacci numbers in it
constexpr auto FibonacciNumber = generateArray<MaxArraySize64BitFibonacci>(getFibonacciNumber);
// End of: All done during compile time -----------------------------------------------------------

// Some debug test driver code
int main() {
    for (const auto f : FibonacciNumber) std::cout << f << ' '; std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

---

By the way. The `generateArray` fucntionality will of course also work with other generator functions.

If you need for example triangle numbers, then you could use:

```
constexpr size_t getTriangleNumber(size_t row) noexcept {
    size_t sum{};
    for (size_t i{ 1u }; i <= row; i++) sum += i;
    return sum;
}
```

and

```
constexpr auto TriangleNumber = generateArray<100>(getTriangleNumber);
```

would give you a compile time calculated `constexpr std::array<size_t, 100>`

So, a rather flexible helper.

---

Developed and tested with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.8.2.

Additionally compiled and tested with clang11.0 and gcc10.2

Language: C++17